# Operator Overloading (==)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm having some difficulty with this. I've determined I need to overload this operator for my personal project. It is necessitated by the use of the following line:

```
if(playerVec[i] == 0)
```

The player class has several data members for calculating one particular data member, mInitiative. This is the one I want to check in my if condition. Here is my attempt at overloading it:

```
bool operator==(const Player& lhs) const {
    return mInitiative == lhs.mInitiative;
}
```

It seems fine enough, but the error persists. If I want to compare that particular player datum to an integer (in this case, 0), how do I go about it? What's the mistake in my approach?

**EDIT:** I have tried:

```
 bool operator==(const Player& lhs, int rhs) const {
    //...
 }
```

But the compiler says there are too many parameters for the function. Why is this? Shouldn't == be able to take two?

Thanks!

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Try to declare operators that don't directly modify the object outside the class, it makes things much clearer.

Comment: Your operator takes a right-hand side of type `Player` but you're passing an `int`.

Comment: You can declare overloads that take mixed types, e.g. `bool operator==(const Player &lhs, int rhs) { ... }`, however you strongly consider whether this is a good idea.  Is it unequivocally clear to the reader of your code what it means to compare a player and an integer?

Comment: It should be. I should note that my main problem is it seems that the operator overload doesn't want to take more than the one argument. I was wondering why this was. I get the error "Too many parameters for this function" when I try.

Comment: @Rome_Leader Because it is a member function and operators that are member to a class take only one argument, the right hand side.

Comment: Ahh, OK. So I should declare it outside the class.

Comment: @Rome_Leader Yes, you should do that. But remember that the extra `const` after the parameter list doesn't belong there because it is *not* a member function.

Comment: Thanks! All better after I declared outside the class! Yes, I remember. Thanks again!

Comment: No, you want to compare it with int, not Player class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to overload an equality operator: declare it as a member, taking one argument (rhs); or declare it as a global, taking two arguments (lhs and rhs). Since your lhs is a `Player`, and your `rhs` is an integer, here are the two ways to define it:

```
// declared inside Player class as a member
bool operator == (int rhs) const
{
    return mInitiative == rhs;
}

// can also be declared inside Player class, but is not a member due to friend keyword
friend bool operator == (Player const& lhs, int rhs)
{
    return lhs.mInitiative == rhs;
}
```

That is leaving aside the style considerations of overloading operators in such a way.

Comment: Note that in both cases, it's wise to declare a further overload for symmetry (otherwise you won't be able to do `0 == player`).

Comment: That is true, although you will only be able to do that with the second declaration, since member operator will always treat the argument as rhs. Besides, that is mostly useful if your class is intended to behave like a numeric type; in other cases, perhaps overloading an operator is not a good idea at all.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to overload equality operator (i.e. `==`), you always need to think about whether the target instances are really the same.

In your case, I think people might be confused when reading the following code if you provide the Player to integer comparison.  Since it looks like checking whether a pointer is null or not:

```
if(playerVec[i] == 0)
```

Rather than overloading == operator of Player to compare with integer, I would suggest providing a get() function, which allows you to compare Player with integer more clearly. For example:

```
if (playerVec[i].getPlayerID() == 0)
```

If you will use some stl function to manage your Player vector (eg. sorting), then you can overload `==` or `>` operator for two Player instances.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a distinction between a player ID and the whole player.

Comment: I've done what I wanted to do, but your suggestion is interesting and may improve readability, so I'll look into making such a distinction. Thanks!

Comment: @Rome_Leader:  You're definitely welcome. I have edited my answer, and I hope it will make things more clearer.